# Search two words in string to verify that one word precedes the other word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

After a lot of googling, asking question on here.  I want to be able to search a string to verify that one word precedes the other (in php), but not necessarily adjacent to each other.  I was so sure it would be simple, but struggled to find an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the only requirement, then maybe:

```
if(($pos = strpos($haystack, $first_word)) !== false && strpos($haystack, $second_word, $pos)) {
    // $second_word found after $first_word
}
```

Comment: But, this still passes if there is a duplicate first word after the second `"first  second  first"` I guess you could build arrays of positions for each word, then sort them then compare element by element. Or, you could use regular expressions.

Comment: That wasn't stated as a requirement.  More rules are needed to expand on this.  How about `second first second`?

Comment: Yeah, to cover edge conditions it's tough `^(?:(?!second).)*first(?:(?!second|first).)*second(?:(?!first).)*$`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if (preg_match('~^(?>[^bg]+|\B[bg]|b(?!adword\b)|g(?!oodword))*+\bgoodword\b~', $str, $match))
    echo 'ok';
else
    echo 'fail';
```

*you must take the first letter of `"badword"` ("b") and allows it only if it is not followed by `"adword"`*

`^` is an anchor for the start of the string

`\b` is a word boundary and `\B` is the opposite.

`(?!...)` means "not followed by"

An example with some text stored into variable :`$text_before`, `$text_after`

```
$flb = preg_quote($text_before[0]);
$fla = preg_quote($text_after[0]);
$subb = substr($text_before, 1);
$suba = substr($text_after, 1);

if( preg_match('~^(?>[^' . $flb . $fla . ']+|\B[' . $flb . $fla ']|'
             . $flb . '(?!\Q' . $subb . '\E\b)|'
             . $fla . '(?!\Q' . $suba . '\E\b))*+\b'
             . $text_after . '\b~', $str, $match) ) {
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yet again, stackoverflow proves to be most helpful resource. I did get it to work using code below, but wasn't convinced it was robust. preg_match("/\b(".$textBefore."|".$textAfter.")\b/", $this->response)  Your solution looks a lot more robust, so will try it out.

Comment: @user2686371: I have updated my answer since I have forgotten something in my pattern and I have added a code example with this technic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
 #  ^(?:(?!word_after).)*word_before(?:(?!word_after|word_before).)*word_after(?:(?!word_before).)*$

 ^ 
 (?:
      (?! word_after )
      . 
 )*

 word_before 

 (?:
      (?! word_after | word_before )
      . 
 )*

 word_after

 (?:
      (?! word_before )
      . 
 )*
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought to suggest you to use strpos(), but maybe it can't work if you need to match the exact words. I'm investigating on something like this:

```
function AbeforeBinC($a, $b, $string)
{
    $aStr = explode(' ', strtolower($string));
    foreach($aStr AS $k => $s)
    {
    if($a == $s){ $a = $k; }
    if($b == $s){ $b = $k; }
    }
    var_dump($a < $b);
}

$str = "We are here to take care of you";

AbeforeBinC('are', 'take', $str);
```